# Definite Integrals with Substitution.

Tags: integration

How would you use the substitution: $x=1+sin\theta$ to evaluate $\int_{0}^{π/2}\frac{cos\theta}{(1+sin\theta)^3}d\theta$.

Furthermore what would you when changing the limits, since its a definite integral.

Comment: Any tries or thoughts yourself? It is a somewhat simple example...

Comment: What would you do to find the answer.

Comment: Like what would you do to find the new limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{(1+\sin(x))^3}\right)\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\sin(x)+1$ and $\text{d}u=\cos(x)\text{d}x$ and 
$
\begin{cases}
x=0 \Longrightarrow u=\sin(0)+1=1\\\
x=\frac{\pi}{2} \Longrightarrow u=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1=2 \\
\end{cases}
$:

---

$$\int_{1}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{u^3}\right)\text{d}u=$$
$$\int_{1}^{2}\left(u^{-3}\right)\text{d}u=$$
$$\left[-\frac{1}{2u^2}\right]_{1}^{2}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{u^2}\right]_{1}^{2}=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{1^2}\right)=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{1}\right)=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}-1\right)=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)=$$
$$--\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=$$
$$\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}=$$
$$\frac{3}{8}$$

Comment: What would you do to find the new limits

Comment: @Elliot-S00 Look to my edit!

Comment: You forgot to make u=1+sinx

Comment: I didn't, look good to my answer!